# Why header doesn't use the full of width?

Tags: android

I Created a simple base table layout, which works perfectly most of the time.

I created two fragment which implements my table fragment, but the fragment headers doesn't use the full width when I use these fragments with ViewPager. Off course if I open these fragments without ViewPager, like I navigate on with navigation drawer, it's use the full width.

In layout inspector I see, the linear layout which is a container picks up the full of width but the parent table row doesn't, but why?

In this picture you can see, the layout seems good without viewpager:
[image: Good one]

In this picture you can see the fail in the view with viewpager:
[image: Wrong one]

Simple Table Fragment layout

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/simple_table_recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
            android:paddingStart="6dp"
            android:paddingEnd="6dp"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:listitem="@layout/opened_customer_orders_table_list_item" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_simple_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
            tools:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.Crm.NoActionBar">

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_simple_search_list_search_card_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
                    app:cardElevation="2dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/simple_table_SearchText"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white" />

                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/simple_table_header_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingStart="6dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="6dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/orderreturn_load_more_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            app:showHide="@{loadingMore}" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment 1 header

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/open_offers_table_header_table_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fragment_open_offers_number_of_offers_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fragment_open_offers_name_of_offers_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fragment_open_offers_transfer_date_title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fragment_open_offers_answer_date_title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

In SimpleTableFragment I hust add the header view to simple_table_header_container

```
baseBinding.simpleTableHeaderContainer.addView(headerDataBinding.root)
```

UPDATE

In layout inpector under Attributes, I noticed that, my table_row width is set to wrap_content, but in the header layout file I set up to match_parent. I think it is all because view pager

Can I samehow force the width to match parent?

Comment: In the Fragment 1 header, I can see you have given layout_weight= "1", for that to work you need to add  android:weightSum="5.0" inside <LinearLayout> and add android:layout_width="0dp" inside <TextView>

Comment: Thanks, but It didn't help, it even got worse